# Reverse scroll wheel only works in some applications

Tags: mouse-scroll

I have successfully used [this advice](https://www.maketecheasier.com/reverse-mouse-scrolling-direction-in-ubuntu/) to reverse the mousewheel scrolling direction in select few applications (firefox, whatever pdf viewer, libreoffice) but not others (nemo, xterm, xed). I'm wondering if there's some wider-reaching setting I can edit here to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your X11 input driver, you might be able to reverse the scroll direction at the X layer.

I'm using `libinput` input driver for my input devices (package `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`), and I use the following configuration (in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/90-libinput-settings`):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput pointer catchall"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
        Option "NaturalScrolling" "1"
EndSection
```

If you're using the `synaptics` input driver, it might be something like [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics#Natural_scrolling) (with negative values for `VertScrollDelta` and `HorizScrollDelta` -- choose a value that you like):

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Option "VertScrollDelta" "-100"
        Option "HorizScrollDelta" "-100"
EndSection
```